# Is there a way to set an exact match between a connected device via adb and via mtp?

Tags: android, adb, mtp, wpd

Using adb I get the serial number of the connected devices `adb devices -l`. Using WPD, I get connected devices and view the properties of `WPD_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER`. On some smartphones, the serial numbers received using adb and wpd do not match.

As a temporary solution, there is an option to download the file via adb and then check its availability via mtp. But I would like to know if there are any other options on how to establish compliance but not by serial numbers?

Comment: A good question. I find it very surprising that you found a ways that matches at least for some devices.